# Motion of Electrons when no Electric Field is applied

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, charge

According to my textbook when no electric field is applied,

> The elecrons in the solid conductor will be moving due to thermal motion during which they collide with the fixed ions. An electron colliding with an ion emerges with the same speed as before collision.

In the end, they conclude that since there is no preferred direction of the electron coming out due to collision, the number of electrons travelling in one direction will be equal to the electrons travelling in the opposite direction so there will be no net electric current.

I wanted to know why the speed of the moving electron is same before and after collision. Is it because it is an elastic collision or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

**On average** *an electron colliding with an ion emerges with the same speed as before collision* because the mobile electrons are in thermal equilibrium with the lattice ions.